# Bosun + Logstash - how to configure alert?

Tags: logstash, bosun

Trying to configure alerts based on logstash query

Here is my simplified config:

```
logstashElasticHosts = http://<url>:9200

alert logstash.errorrate.exceeds1 {
    template = generic
    $notes = "The rate of errors in 5 sec exceeds 1."
    $lastday = lscount("prod", "level:ERROR", "level:ERROR", "5s", "10m", "")
    $lastDayMax = max($lastday)
    warn = $lastDayMax > 1
    warnNotification = email
}
```

And I'm recieving neither normal nor warning result while testing alert on bosun/config page:

```
criticals: 0, warnings: 0, normals: 0, errors: 0
```

So what am I doing wrong?
(Elastic works ok. I've checked with Kibana UI.)

Comment: Start with `lscount("prod", "level:ERROR", "", "5s", "10m", "")` on the expression page and make sure there are actual results

Answer (score 2):

The issue was in `keyString/filterString` case. It's strange but while the level logged as `ERROR` (in upper case), the query works only in lower case: `"level:error"` but not `"level:ERROR"`.